# SQL Count then Sum and average for specific student

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of students with their scores listed by `Submitdate`. I'm trying to calculate the SUM, TOTAL, then AVERAGE of each student. Here is my table with data:

```
StudentsTbl
-------------
ID G1 G2  Submitdate
-------------------
01 8  9   2017-11-06
01 9  10  2017-11-18
01 7  8   2017-12-09
02 6  8   2017-10-08
02 9  10  2017-11-25
03 9  10  2017-10-18
03 7  6   2017-11-15
03 8  9   2017-12-08
03 7  8   2017-12-25
```

I created this query to calculate each student's average and total, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT AVG(G1) AS G1
     , AVG(G2) AS G2
     , (AVG(G1) + AVG(G2)) AS Total
     , (AVG(G1) + AVG(G2))/2 AS Average
FROM StudentsTbl
GROUP BY G1, G2
```

Here is the output I would like to get:

```
ID  G1    G2   Total Average
--------------------------
01 8.00  9.00  17.00  8.50
02 7.50  9.00  16.50  9.75
03 7.75  8.25  16.00  8.00
```

Comment: You need to read about how GROUPing works. You are grouping by the wrong thing. Think about what makes the data a group. That is what you want to group by, not the detail columns.

Comment: Change `GROUP BY G1, G2` by `GROUP BY ID`

Comment: You can't group by an alias you gave an AGGREGATED action. you can group by an underline column or other NON aggregated functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are int you need to cast them

```
declare @t table (ID int, G1 int, G2 int); 
insert into @t values 
       (01, 8,  9)  
     , (01, 9, 10) 
     , (01, 7,  8)   
     , (02, 6,  8)  
     , (02, 9, 10) 
     , (03, 9, 10)  
     , (03, 7,  6)   
     , (03, 8,  9)   
     , (03, 7,  8);
with cte as 
( SELECT id
       , AVG(cast(G1 as smallmoney)) AS G1
       , AVG(cast(G2 as smallmoney)) AS G2
   FROM @t
  GROUP BY ID 
)
select *
    , (G1 + G2) as TOTAL  
    , (G1 + G2)/2 as AVERAGE  
from cte
order by id;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to group by the `ID`:

```
SELECT AVG(G1) AS G1,
       AVG(G2) AS G2,
       (AVG(G1) + AVG(G2)) AS Total,
       (AVG(G1) + AVG(G2))/2 AS Average
FROM StudentsTbl
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Mathematically, Avg(G1) + Avg(G2) is the same as Avg(G1 + G2)

Comment: @GMastros agreed, but you should have this comment on the question as a recommendation, not here as I'm not the one who wrote that.